# Illustrator: how to create dynamic curved text with curved background boxes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Currently I'm creating this by hand (attached picture). Is there any way I could automate this process, so when I resize the circle, the boxes stay the same height.

[image]

Right now, when I resize and keep the font size the same, this happens:
[image]

Suggestions for other tools beside illustrator where this could be done are also welcome!

Comment: Well you could write a eps file that handles this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator is not really a scene graph description language. I mean it has some functions for a effects stack, but it can not freely interlink basic things.

So there is no expectation that 2 separate elements can be linked. So there is nothing in illustrator user interface that inherently allows size of circle to drive placement of box.

Can this be done? Well naturally you can script this, you can inject a eps file that does this or you can make your own plugin effect. You can also try to build this with a bend wrap but i don't think thats especially valid solution.

Anyway its hard to advice what to choose as a strategy as ultimately it depends on how you use this automation in the first place. You could use LaTeX ant TiKz for example. You could generate a svg or pdf, you could just directly do this in printer code, in browser etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please select your object. Please Follow this commend: Choose Object > Transform > Scale.
Options select:
Scale Corners and Scale Strokes @ Effects And then click Ok.

Comment: Not sure, how this is related to my problem? Check the second picture I posted.